# Django and Amazon Lambda: Best solution for big data with Amazon RDS or GraphQL or Amazon AppSync

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, graphql, aws-appsync

We have a system with large data (about 10 million rows in on a table). We developed it in Django framework and also we want to use Amazon Lambda for serving it. Now I have some question about it:
1- If we want to use Amazon RDS (MySql, PostgresSQL), which one is better? And relational database is a good solution for doing this?

2- I read somewhere, If we want to use a relational database in Amazon Lambda, Django for each instance, opens a new connection to the DB and it is awful. Is this correct?

3- If we want to use GraphQL and Graph database, Is that a good solution? Or we can combine Django Rest-API and GraphQL together?

4- If we don't use Django and use Amazon AppSync, Is better or not? What are our limitations for use this.

Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

GraphQL is very useful for graph data, not timeseries. Your choice will depend on the growth factor, not the actual rows. I currently run an RDS instance with 5 billion rows just fine, but the problem is how it will increase over time. I suggest looking into archival strategies using things like S3 or IoT-analytics (this one is really cool).

I wouldn't worry about concurrent connections until you have a proper reason too (+50's per second). Your DB will be the largest server you have anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, We are importing about 10000 rows in 24 hours, but we are reading or querying data about 10000 times in a minute.